# Creating the same kind of navigation with HTML & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

Hello people of Stackoverflow,

I'm looking to build the same navigation as used on the website Pagekit.com. The navigation has to pop up after scrolling for a bit. Anyone knows jQuery plugins or anything else which can do the trick for me? I've done some Googling but couldn't find anything usefull.

Best Regards,
Dylan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is: scrollPosition.

The Result you want to achieve is a bit too much to explain every single action you have to take. Here is an example of what you are looking for: [FadeIn on scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/e5qaD/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks got it sorted sir!